# How to ask a good subjective question

Tags: discussion

There's a new post at the Stack Exchange blog: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). It's well worth reading.

The gist is that it is indeed possible to ask subjective questions within the Stack Exchange framework, within certain limits.

This in particular resonates for me:

> The folks at Moms4mom owned up to the subjective issue and came up with a set of principles to create useful subjective discussions on parenting: the Back It Up! Principle. Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either:
>
> - Something that happened to you personally
> - Something you can back up with a reference
>
> They talk about how “opinion, by itself, is noise.” They’re not saying that subjective opinions are to be avoided; they’re attempting to mold and shape their inherently subjective Q&A into something constructive, informative and helpful. As it turns out, there is an entire field of subjective “expertise” that has the hallmarks of making great Q&A sites:

The post continues with guidelines for asking subjective questions, and I can't think of much here that doesn't follow them. Most of the questions asked here have been pretty focused, with a very few exceptions.

What does everyone else think?

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Is listening to music dangerous while cycling?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/623/is-listening-to-music-dangerous-while-cycling) is a good example of how a 'subjective' question can work on SE.  What differentiates the SE from a normal forum is

- Feedback on the question to narrow the original focus where necessary
- multiple good answers to the original question (addressing the question, not someone else's answer)
- discussion about answers allowed for, but limited to comments
- and, it's got to be said, a user group who are prepared to not abuse the system, avoid taking the bait, or otherwise allow borderline questions descend into chaos.

Comment: Yeah, I cringed when I first saw the title on that one, but I slowly realized that it is indeed a good question to ask -- here. The answers are civilized and useful, and theres good information in that question about why people do what they do.